Is FloatingLinkEditorPlugin still available in @lexical/react?
I am tring to create a link button in my RCE I am making with Lexical. I am trying to import the FloatingLinkEditorPlugin, but its not included with the package. With everything I am reading it should be.
This is what I am getting:
Module not found: Error: Package path ./LexicalFloatingLinkEditorPlugin is not exported from package /var/www/html/node_modules/@lexical/react (see exports field in /var/www/html/node_modules/@lexical/react/package.json)

`
Is there a different import that this?
import { FloatingLinkEditorPlugin } from '@lexical/react/LexicalFloatingLinkEditorPlugin' 
If that plugin is no longer being used, is there another option that lexical has?
I've tried intall more specific packages and searching up more detatils, but there insn't a lot of documentation for lexical that has been helpful in this matter.
